# Printing a string in Java using less characters than the contents of the string

Tags: java, string, minify

This is for an extra credit assignment in school that will be coming up next semester. I have to print a paragraph to the screen but the amount of characters is the code must be less than the amount of characters in the paragraph. The paragraph is below:

> "I pledge that every program with my name on it shall be written by me (and my co-authors, if any) and that I fully understand the program. Every program I submit shall be entirely my own work unless otherwise attributed. I understand that academic dishonesty not only includes copying other people's work, but also abetting or facilitating copying. Code that is similar to any other submission past or present will get no credit whatever the explanation. I understand that the consequence of academic dishonesty is a grade of 'F' for the class. I pledge to devote my efforts to learning Java by writing my own programs. I shall strive to be attentive to detail and write programs understandable by myself and other programmers."
>
> The total number of characters in the program should be fewer that the total number of characters in the pledge (655 printable, 793 total).

The program can take no input whatsoever...no files, downloading, etc.

My initial thought was that since no one has ever been able to do it, it must be outside the scope of what we've learned in class so far. Since it has to be less, you obviously can't just println the paragraph line by line which is what everyone does in the first part (regular credit) of the assignment.

I have researched string compression using java.util.zip but I keep running into the problem that no input is allowed. An idea that I've back shelved for now is: Is there a way to code the strings in compressed form, making the code less characters than the uncompressed version of the paragraph, and simply uncompress the string as I print it to the console?

I've also dabbled with ASCII values, however, the ASCII values represent characters only AND all ASCII values have longer character length than the character they would be used to represent so I didn't see the use for that.

The idea that I have settled on for now is to take the longest repeated words and assign them a string variable name. Then, simply substitute the words in the paragraph with the variable concatenation style. This is my code so far:

```
import static java.lang.System.out;

public class Pledge {
  public static void main(String[] args){
    String s=" understand ",p=" program",z=" academic dishonesty ",c=" copying",i="I pledge ";
    out.println(i+"that every"+p+" with my name on it shall be written by me (and my co-authors, if any) and that i fully"+s+"the"+p+". Every"+p+" I submit shall be entirely my own work unless otherwise attributed. I"+s+"that"+z+"not only includes"+c+" other people's work, but also abetting or facilitating"+c+". Code that is similar to any other submission past");
    out.println("or present will get no credit whatever the explanation. I"+s+"that the consequence of"+z+"is a grade of 'F' for the class."+i+"to devote my efforts to learning Java by writing my own"+p+"s. I shall strive to be attentive to detail and write"+p+"s "+s+"able by myself and other"+p+"mers.");
  }
}
```

The attached code is 762 printable characters. Since I am 112 characters off and the code already looks terrible with two giant println statements, I kind of feel like I am not on the right track. I don't expect any code to be written for me (I hate that), but a few hints or tips to push me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Hint: Take a look at builtin compression like [`java.util.zip`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/zip/package-summary.html)

Comment: @MikeSamuel You still need to include the contents of the `zip` in the source file. The pledge, bzipped and base64-encoded is 580 characters. That leaves you with 210 characters for the uncompress, decode, and printing, which might be pushing it. (Especially since there's no straightforward way to deflate a byte array.)

Comment: unfortunately the 762 is only the printable characters (not including spaces). That number must be less than 655

Comment: @MikeSamuel Actually, scratch that, seems like there's `Deflater`

Comment: @millimoose, Fair enough.  For larger texts, the zip savings might push you over the edge, and in languages like Perl, you can efficiently combine data and program in the same file, but I guess this text just isn't big enough.

Comment: Remove the space after understand since you're using it for understandable.

Comment: @user1843232 You can also shave off some characters by: 1) Losing the `import static`. `System.out` is shorter than `import static java.lang.System.out`. 2) Don't use multiple `out.println()` statements - replace them with `\n`. This will save almost 50 characters.

Comment: Characters can be pretty large. If you encode data using the printable part of Unicode, you may store a lot of bits. Code looks like (and probably contains) Chinese, but hey :)

Comment: Well, the text says the program should be less than the total, your program is 876, leaving you only 83 off the total.

Comment: @owlstead That's not very useful if the compressed data isn't valid UTF-8.

Comment: Also, if you're allowed, shorten the class name to something like `P`. Basically, golf like you've never golfed before. Just by golfing your original code I got down to 803 characters, this might not even need anything clever.

Comment: I'm down to 798... can't find where I shall save the last missing characters to acheive the goal, which might not be acheivable in the first place. That while formatting the text as it is in the question, if the text can be on one line, I would be down to 792.

Comment: @MikeSamuel Shockingly, after much golfing, the `zip` solution gets down to 750 chars. I've put it on ideone: http://ideone.com/r920A7. (To the OP: don't click on that link unless you want a spoiler. It's rather unlikely you'd be able to explain how it works at the hand-in, so it's better if you'd try to implement the approach yourself - now you at least know that the approach will work.)

Comment: @millimoose, Incidentally, now that you've got the output up on the web, there's a simple solution that uses `java.net.URLConnection` to fetch the output from `ideone.com`, strip off the rest, and print it.  Alternatively, use a `URLClassLoader` to load your solution and a little reflection to run it.

Comment: @MikeSamuel I think that would fly in the face of the "no input" rule. (It's also a fantastically convoluted way of getting a line of text from a URL and I want to have its babies.)

Comment: Another option of the "shaving off bytes" persuasion: using [`MessageFormat.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#format(java.lang.String, java.lang.Object...)). It adds some "overhead" because of the extra function call, but it will "compress" any substring of the original string that's 4 characters or longer, as long as it's used more than I'd say twice. It also lets us get rid of the string variables.

Comment: @millimoose, "Input" is what you accept.  "Conanput" is what you seize from atop a pile of bodies of slain enemies.  Conan doesn't bend homework rules, he breaks them so badly no-one even remembers they were there.  "I pledge to make every Java program whimper in fear at the sound of my name."

Comment: I think that your school is focusing on the wrong thing.

Comment: @Isaac Well, it's an extra credit question that requires some familiarity with (or exploring of) the standard libraries. If it was a required assignment you'd be completely right, it doesn't seem reasonable to assume a student should be able to come up with these solutions himself at this level. (Which I'm guessing is introductory classes.) For an optional assignment it's a wash. That said, ironically – given the pledge of doom – it seems to me the OP would probably learn more about the JDK by comparing the various solutions he got here than he would by just stumbling on one solution himself.

Comment: The problem I see with the zip solution is one could argue that getting the characters to make the pledge requires something, the odds are getting those manually, by which I mean without the help of another program, would take a long time. That alone makes me think that solution isn't a proper one.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau That's kind of splitting hairs though, isn't it? Not like uni instructors aren't great at splitting hairs, but it's the kind of pettifoggery you'd resort to if you wanted to refuse every solution than the one you had in mind. (As opposed to rewarding some measure of lateral thinking.)

Comment: @millimoose We could say so but I felt important to mention it. Note that it might actually be the only solution but I would still think it's kinda a cheated one.

Comment: @JonathanDrapeau Regardless of how you feel about it, dismissing the solution based on said feeling would be a jerk move, period. It fits the letter of the assignment requirements completely. Arguing it violates some sort of spirit of the requirements is moving the goalposts, and plain and simply unfair. (For what it's worth, it's not the only workable approach. Scattered in the comments I've linked to two other solutions, one of which is even "cheatier".)

Answer (score 2):

One thing you might want to look into is [Huffman encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Huffman_coding). The approach is *similar* to that in the program you posted, but much more thorough in terms of how it compresses the paragraph. So you could compress the text (beforehand), place the compressed version in your source file, uncompress and print.

Also there are little tricks here and there that can shave off a few characters as well; for example,

- `main(String[] args)` could be `main(String[]v)` (4 chars saved)
- You can use a name shorter than `Pledge`, maybe a single-character name (5 chars saved)
- You can put everything on one line (many chars saved)

They're little things but they'll add up.

Comment: A one-liner program would save a lot of characters indeed.

Answer (score 1):

A creative solution might be to write your program in Unicode and encoding the string using UTF-16.  This allows you to store the string using half the number of 'printable characters'.  For example:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String s = "䤠灬敤来⁴桡琠敶敲礠灲潧牡洠";
    System.out.println(new String(s.getBytes("UTF-16BE"),"UTF-8"));
}
```

prints `I pledge that every program`.  The output is 28 characters, but the number of 'printable characters' used to store the string is only 14.  With 793 printable characters to encode, you'd need 397 characters for the string, leaving you with 258 to work with for actual code.

Comment: How do you create those characters? The chinese looking ones?

Comment: I'm surprised that arbitrary pairs of ASCII characters are valid UTF-16 sequences.

Comment: @user1843232 Just do the opposite of what this snippet does for your entire input string.

Comment: so I would code the whole pledge in String s using that language and then the getbytes() tells the compiler which character set to print it out in?

Comment: it would map each one of those characters to a ASCII valued character?

Comment: @user1843232 No, the idea is to map two ASCII characters to one UTF-16 character. The trick is that a UTF-16 character still takes up two bytes - it relies on being able to argue semantics of "character" versus "byte".

Comment: @KevinK: Unless my round-trip code is wrong, this won't work for some reason: http://ideone.com/KapoXg. The result of the round-trip is almost but not quite the same as the original, so it might still be possible to tweak things to make this correct.

Comment: Right, this seems to work too: http://ideone.com/iqPuCw, **iif** the characters are counted with `wc -m`. (The link is also a massive spoiler without an explanation why it works.)

Comment: @millimoose I'll be honest, I'm surprised it maps to printable characters myself.  I did test with the full paragraph, but didn't include it in my answer since this is homework.

Comment: @KevinK Considering the menacing nature of the pledge, I trust the OP to not hand in a copy/pasted solution that's abstruse in nature and requires a blob of gibberish kanji and ideograms and some arbitrary tweaking of the output data without being able to confidently explain how it works.

Comment: @millimoose note that this answer is basically my comment, although the mapping may leave a bit to be desired (then again, if it works)

Comment: @owlstead Indeed it is. (With the verbose debate, I lost track of who proposed which idea, I just tried to implement a few as I saw them.)

Answer (score 0):

A refinement of your current approach is using [`printf()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29) and its [explicit argument indexing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#dpos) feature. This will both save you 1 character for every occurence in the original string (thus letting you "compress" shorter substrings. It also gets rid of the string variable declaration, which is three fewer characters per substring and a bit.

The spoilerrific ideone version is here: http://ideone.com/lnrTrG – I managed to get it down to 784 characters, without having to use anything exceedingly clever. It's also possible that my choice of extracted substrings wasn't optimal.

I tried achieving the same using [`MessageFormat.format()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/MessageFormat.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29), but it wouldn't replace all the placeholders. Considering how close to the limit the `printf()` version is, it's possible that the ability to compress shorter substrings (because `MessageFormat`'s explicit-index placeholders are one character shorter than `printf()`'s) wouldn't even offset the extra 32 characters of overhead from `java.text.MessageFormat.format()`. (That said, it might be worth a try. You save 29 characters on the placeholders alone so it's close.)

---

There's also a direct answer to another point in your question:

> Is there a way to code the strings in compressed form, making the code less characters than the uncompressed version of the paragraph, and simply uncompress the string as I print it to the console?

You've already found `java.util.zip`, the missing piece of the puzzle is [*base-64 encoding*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64). This will let you store the compressed bytes in a String consisting of printable characters. It will take up more characters than the length of the encoded array, but (luckily) far fewer than the original string. (It should also be shorter than writing out the byte array values directly.) You can use the utility methods of [`DatatypeConverter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html) to work with this encoding. (Thanks to @owlstead for the tip.)

An even better method proposed by my coworker that's even better than base-64 is simply encoding the zipped data using a legacy character set like Latin-1. Since most Latin-1 characters are printable, they can be written in a Java string literal using one character. The few that will need escaping will still be less bloat than base-64. If your source file can also be encoded in Latin-1, this will also avoid having to argue the difference between characters and bytes.

Comment: Another tiny optimisation got me to 772 characters when golfed: http://ideone.com/xSaTFs

Comment: http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/DatatypeConverter.html